# plotting changes over time in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner with Python
I'm have a series of 24 values in an array, each corresponding to an hour of the day:
values = [684,434,399,248,347,374,303,846,1994,3096,3209,3820,3827,4391,4716,4284,4042,2793,1820,1493,1310,1015,1117,1186]

and I also made an array of strings for the hours
times = ['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00','06:00','07:00','08:00','09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00']

How can I use matplotlib to plot each value as a y-value and each hour along the x-axis, with a line connecting each point? So far I've only found ways to plot when the x-axis has actual numerical values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the labels on the x-axis using `xticks`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = np.array([684, 434, ... , 1186])
times = np.arange(0,len(values))
time_labels = ['00:00', '01:00', ..., '23:00']

plt.plot(times, values, 'o-')
plt.xticks(times, time_labels)
plt.show()
```

That should give you connected circles with the hour strings on the x-axis.

[image]